# switching images with setTimeout

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change some images after click.
Initially I have image called let's say image1. After click I wanted to change it to: image2.
Problem is that after 1 sec, I want to again go back to initial image (image1).

my code looks like this:

```
    <script>
$(window).load(function() {

    $('#rounded-corner #mtg_card').click(function()
        {
            $(this).find(".mtg_shop_cart").attr("src","image1");
            window.setTimeout(function() {
              $(this).find(".mtg_shop_cart").attr("src","image2");
            }, 1000);
            return false;
        });
});

</script>
```

Comment: is there only two images?

Answer (score 0):

You need to cache `this` in some other variable, then use that variable in `setTimeout` function

Use

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('#rounded-corner #mtg_card').click(function () {
        $(this).find(".mtg_shop_cart").prop("src", "image1");
        var self = this; //Cache this in a variable
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $(self).find(".mtg_shop_cart").prop("src", "image2"); //Use cached variable here
        }, 1000);
        return false;
    });
});
```

or

A elegant approach is to use `.bind(this)`

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('#rounded-corner #mtg_card').click(function () {
        $(this).find(".mtg_shop_cart").attr("src", "image1");
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $(this).find(".mtg_shop_cart").attr("src", "image2");
        }.bind(this), 1000); //Here use .bind(this)
        return false;
    });
});
```